# Grab checked input and send it in json format using AJAX jQuery and a POST request. Using Flask

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json, flask

Hi So I am having issues trying to send the checked data of a form using a button I configured for submission. The checked data is coming in using a 'GET' request and that works phenomenally using flask. However, once I make a checklist I want to click submit and send the data using either POST or GET (depends which one is better), but I have to use flask to retrieve the form data using JSON format (since I am familiar with this seeing as I used this format to retrieve the data to go into the checklist form) Here is what i have tried

Flask:

```
@app.route('/echo/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def echo():
    error = None
    #ret_data = {"value": request.args.get('echoValue')}
    #data = jsonify(ret_data)
    #dic = {"test" : "Data successfully recieved!", "test1":"sss"}
    if request.method == 'GET':
        dic = dictionary()
        time.sleep(10)
        return jsonify(dic)
    else:
        error = 'Fail in "GET"'
        return render_template('index.html', error=error)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.args.get('Device1', '')
        return jsonify(data)
```

Now here is my jquery for the POST as well as how I am retrieving the form data and adding it into an empty object.

```
$('#Submit').click(function() {
    var num_checked_devices = $('input:checked').length;
    var oElements = {};
    $('#form1 input:checked').each(function() {
      oElements[this.name] = this.value;
    });

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + "/echo/",
      data: oElements,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function(data) {
        $('#test').text(data['Device1']);
      }
    });
```

The HTML is as follows, but keep in mind that the form is empty for the reason that the data comes in using the GET jquery code that I did not post.

```
<form id='form1'>
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Add Devices" />
<button type='button' id='Submit' name='Submit Button'>Add Devices</button>
<button type='button' id='Refresh' name='Refresh Button'>Refresh</button>

<br /><br />
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Flask, but I do know that the [jQuery Forms Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) makes submitting forms ajax-style easy. Your checkboxes should come through as if it were a typical (i.e. not-ajaxy) form.

Comment: jQuery doesn't automatically turn you object to json you have to do it manually. `data: JSON.stringify(oElements),`

Comment: The Maniac-Thanks for the tip, I will try using this plugin. But can this plugin add more inputs? Currently I have my form growing depending on how many bluetooth devices are found, which can be anywhere from 1 to n number of devices.

Comment: Musa, so for you are saying that even though JSON format looks like an object it doesn't convert it into JSON? I am iffy about this since I just ran the jquery and looked at the Developer Tools on Chrome to see what the jQuery was sending and this is what I got:

Comment: Device2=2&Device3=3 under Network->Headers->Request Payload, and I have the form look like this:

<input type="checkbox" name="Devicei" value=i>Ubuntu0<br />

where i = 1 to total number of devices.

Comment: So I sort of know already my own answer to this question, BUT since I am new to stackoverflow I can not answer my own question for another 5 hours! lol. I now have an issue with the way the POST is sending the data since it is not sending the full string value of the form input. Does anyone know a better way of submitting this?